# Added image size suggestion text in the Tinymce image dialog

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to add a text suggested image size that will be uploaded by the user. I want to add a message with suggestions (for example: *"for best results use image size 100x100px"*) in red box under dimension column. Please see [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RZQ.jpg)

Is it possible to do it? How best to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to edit css

```css
#size-suggetion {
width: 90vw;
border: 6px solid red;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "size-suggetion">
for best results use image size 100x100px
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this. Just open the plugin code and add the text you need to the dialog.  There is no configuration option to add text to the dialog in random/various locations.